# How to set values to symbols

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbols

I would like to set values to a list of variables, like so:

```
list[[1]] = 2
```

and if `list[[1]]` is `a`, then `a` will now be equal to two. How can I achieve this?

Comment: it would help if we knew the error that list[[1]]=2 throws

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, let's try it naively:

Make a list:

```
In[1]:= ClearAll[list, a, b, c]; 
list = {a, b, c};
```

It's as we expect it:

```
In[3]:= list
Out[3]= {a, b, c}
```

Set the first element to 2:

```
In[4]:= list[[1]] = 2
Out[4]= 2

In[5]:= list
Out[5]= {2, b, c}
```

That doesn't affect a:

```
In[6]:= a 
Out[6]= a
```

Start again:

```
In[7]:= ClearAll[list, a, b, c]; 
list = {a, b, c}; 

In[9]:= list
Out[9]= {a, b, c}
```

The problem is that Set (=) has `HoldFirst` as one of its attributes , i.e., it doesn't evaluate its first argument which is the lefthand side, and the assignment is to the list and not to the variable that's in that location. But you can force evaluation using `Evaluate`:

```
In[10]:= Evaluate[list[[1]]] = 2
Out[10]= 2
```

Now the list seems to be the same as before:

```
In[11]:= list
Out[11]= {2, b, c}
```

but that's only because a is still there and has gotten the value  of 2 (in the previous version a was *replaced* by 2):

```
In[12]:= a
Out[12]= 2
```

If you now set a to 3 you'll  see that that changes list too:

```
In[13]:= a = 3
Out[13]= 3

In[14]:= list
Out[14]= {3, b, c}
```

---

**EDIT**

Perhaps more close to the wording of your question, you could `Map` `Set` over the list:

```
In[16]:= ClearAll[list, a, b, c]; 
list = {a, b, c}; 

In[18]:= Set[#, RandomInteger[10]] & /@ list
Out[18]= {4, 8, 1}

In[19]:= list    
Out[19]= {4, 8, 1}

In[21]:= {a, b, c}    
Out[21]= {4, 8, 1}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `Evaluate[list[[1]]] = 2` will work only until `a` have no value. And in addition to the EDIT part: `{a,b,c}={1,2,3}` works fine too.

Comment: @Alexey Yep, that will work as well but I assume that the OP has a long list of variables to be set that he wants to deal with more automatically. +1 for first remark. Indeed, after a has got a value `Evaluate[list[[1]]]` evaluates to its value rather than to the symbol.

Comment: @Alexey It is good to note that in case the variables have to be set repeatedly Leonid's solution works wonders.

Comment: @Sjoerd I agree. The second part of my comment was irrelevant the original question, sorry.

Comment: @Sjoerd Well, the case in question (symbols already having values) was exactly the reason I bothered with all the evaluation-control stuff in my version. It also reminded me that I often miss pointers/references and structs/classes in mma, but you can't have everything.

Answer (score 9):

What you request is generally hard in Mathematica, since it is hard to imitate the pointer semantics. The following code will do specifically what you asked for, but is restricted to only symbols as list elements:

```
ClearAll[setPart];
SetAttributes[setPart, HoldFirst];
setPart[lst_Symbol, i_, value_] :=
  With[{heldPart =  First@Extract[Hold[lst] /. OwnValues[lst], {{1, i}}, Hold]},
    If[MatchQ[heldPart, Hold[_Symbol]],
      Set @@ Append[heldPart, value],
      lst[[i]] = value]];
```

Examples:

```
In[117]:= Clear[list, a, b]
list = {a, b, c, 4, 5};
a = 1;
b = 3;
list

Out[121]= {1, 3, c, 4, 5}

In[122]:= setPart[list, 1, 10];
{a, list}

Out[123]= {10, {10, 3, c, 4, 5}}

In[124]:= setPart[list, 5, 10];
list

Out[125]= {10, 3, c, 4, 10}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps do:

```
setSymbol[symbol_, value_] := Module[{},
    ToExpression[
        SymbolName[symbol] <> "=" <> ToString[value,TotalWidth->Infinity]
    ]
]
setSymbol[list[[1]], 2]
```

Though that may be a bit hackish. The correct way is by playing around with how values are Held from being evaluated, but I couldn't remember how; see other answers.

Comment: Very hackish, and currently has errors.  `list[1]` should probably be `list[[1]]`, `'='` should be `"="`, and you probably meant to use `ToExpression` instead of `Evaluate` to turn the string back into something that will evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar problem with defining the value of symbols, when you first dont know wich symbol you want to redefine. Your answers helped me to find the right way doing that:

**HoldPattern** worked very well for me here, even if values have been allready set for variables.

```
In[253]:= Clear[a,b,c,d,list]
list = HoldPattern/@{a,b,c,d};
a=2;
Evaluate[list[[1]]]=1;
list//ReleaseHold
a

Out[257]= {1,b,c,d}
Out[258]= 1
```

So my solution is pretty much like the first solution by Sjoerd C. de Vries, but it protects the symbols from being evaluated inside of the list by HoldPattern.

Note, that one has to use **ReleaseHold** to use the list for further calculations. The variables (a,b,c,d) dont get affected by this construction.

This was my first post here, hope you like it ;-)