# Create variable with list of strings

Tags: list, variables, string, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to know if it's possible to use the content of a variable list of strings to create a new variable.

As an example:

```
str={"cow","monkey"}
```

these strings are extracted from a file. Now I would like to refer to these strings as if it was a variable.  So the variable cow could be set to `{4,2,3}` or anything else.  Any reference as `str[[1]]` gives the string "cow" of course.

Any clues or is this a bad idea anyway?

Of course I could add info in the list I already have such as:

```
str={{"cow",{4,2,3}},{"monkey",{}}
```

but then I still won't be able to directly address cow as a variable.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Lou! Don't forget to vote for the answer(s) below that you like and, if one of them answers your question to your satisfaction, please accept it by using the check-mark next to the answer. You can change your choice whenever you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest would be to just manually use symbols `cow` and `monkey` rather than strings:

```
In[309]:= 
cow = 1;
monkey = 2;  
{cow, monkey}

Out[311]= {1, 2}
```

But this is probably not what you asked. If you want to automatically convert strings to variables, then 
what you have to do (if I understood the question correctly) is to first convert your strings to symbols, since symbols can be assigned values and used as variables:

```
Remove[cow,monkey];
str = {"cow", "monkey"};
str1 = ToExpression /@ str

{cow, monkey}
```

(I assume that symbols `cow` and `monkey` have not been used/defined). After that, you can use the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708142/how-to-set-values-to-symbols/5708395) question to assign to the variables based on their positions in `str1`. However, the usefulness of this approach is also questionable.

What I think makes the most sense is to create so called [indexed variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html), such as

```
myIndexedVar["cow"] = 1;
myIndexedVar["monkey"] = 2;
```

where `myIndexedVar` is essentially a hash-table of key-value pairs, with keys being your strings and values being whatever you want to assign to them. The process can be automated if needed.

**EDIT**

To illustrate assignments to such variables, here is a function which automates that:

```
assignVariables[varNames_List, values_List, hashName_Symbol ] /; 
  Length[varNames] == Length[values] :=
    MapThread[(hashName[#1] = #2) &, {varNames, values}];
```

Here is how you can use it:

```
In[316]:= assignVariables[str,{{4,2,3},{}},myIndexedVar]

Out[316]= {{4,2,3},{}}

In[317]:= myIndexedVar["cow"]

Out[317]= {4,2,3}

In[318]:= myIndexedVar["monkey"]

Out[318]= {}
```

But again, this really is a hash-table, so your question makes most sense to me when reformulated as: "I want to make a hash-table with string keys. What's the easiest way to do that in Mathematica, add key-value pairs and access them". The answer seems to be - indexed variables, as illustrated above. You may also find it useful to read on [DownValues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html), since these provide the mechanism for indexed variables.

Comment: You can also use `Symbol[]` as in `Symbol /@ {"cow", "monkey"}`.  I also suggest using indexed variables though.  Or possible a replacement list or dispatch table: `values = Dispatch[{"cow" -> {4,2,3},"monkey" -> {}}]` and `"cow" /. values`. This ensures that there won't be any accidental conflict with already existing symbols.

Comment: @Szabolcs One problem with `Dispatch` is that you can not easily add new key-value pairs once the `Dispatch`-ed  rules are formed, without making a new `Dispatch`-ed rules and associated with that performance hit (don't get me wrong - I am a big fan of `Dispatch` :)). Also, I think that indexed variables must be more intuitive to users coming from other languages, who may understand hash tables but who have not seen replacement rules before.

Comment: This was also in my answer: Your use of `myIndexedVar["cow"]` implies knowledge of the fact that "cow" is in the list. If you know this, why not use the _symbol_ cow instead? If you don't know it's in the list, you can't use the string "cow" as a reference either.

Comment: @Sjoerd I think that using symbols in this setting is very fragile, and mentioned them only to give a full picture (I actually linked to the other SO question for which your answer was accepted) - one can still use positions of symbols in `str1`. As to how to use strings - see my edit - there I used `str` without knowing the names of the string "variables", but just knowing their number. I am not saying that is very sensible, but at least this *may* make some sense - if one wants to add key-value pairs to the hash in some automatic way. Also, I could not see your answer when posting mine :)

Comment: @Sjoerd, that's unfortunately true, and quite annoying, but there's no technical reason for it to be that way.  I wish there were a function to insert new values into a dispatch table.  Are you aware of any differences between how Dispatch and "function definitions" (i.e. f["a"] = 2) work, in particular regarding the ordering of replacement rules?

Comment: @Szabolcs I feel your pain with `Dispatch`. Regarding the rule ordering, `Dispatch` does not reorder the rules, as far as I can tell. `DownValues` does reorder, but you can pass to it the `Sort->False` option to see the original rule ordering. Also, in case of duplicate rule l.h.s., `Dispatch` seems to keep both rules (although will only use the first one), while in `DownValues` only the last-entered rule with the same l.h.s. is stored. Of course, this only tells what you can extract from them - they way rules are used is (for non-patterns) based on internal hash-tables in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

`ToExpression` will convert a string to an expression. `Symbol["x"]` creates the symbol x as the name suggests.

However, I wonder how you plan to use them. If you don't know *a priori* what's in the file with names how are you going to use them? If `str={"cow","monkey"}` and I create a list of symbols with `strSym=ToExpression/@str` then the only way I could continue in my code is to index this second array. I cannot simply say `cow=5` in my code because I don't know at the time  of writing the code that there will be a variable named cow.

```
In[1]:= str = {"cow", "monkey"};
strSym = ToExpression /@ str

Out[2]= {cow, monkey}

In[3]:= strSym[[1]] // Evaluate = 5

Out[3]= 5

In[4]:= ?cow

Global`cow

cow=5
```

As you can see, indexing also requires an additional Evaluate, because Set (=) has HoldFirst as Attribute. So I can't set cow by indexing unless I have the index evaluated otherwise I overwrite the definition of strSym[[1]] .

Comment: @All, Thx for the fast replies. It answers my question and generates some new ones :). I feel that the indexed variables will be the best way to go. I understand Sjoerd's question about the usage of variables that are a priori not known. I was thinking of using this model to make the code more readable and it is not supposed to be a fixed standalone program but more a interactive research notebook.

Answer (score 3):

Leonid's last method is probably the best, but I am fond of replacement rules, therefore I offer:

```
str={"cow","monkey"};

rules = {"cow" -> {4,2,3}, "monkey" -> {}};

str[[1]] /. rules
```

```
  Out = {4, 2, 3}
```

See [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html), and [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) for more.

Comment: The upside of this method is that it is the cleanest one - it does not introduce side effects and is completely declarative. The downside is that, for a novice user, it creates many more questions (such as: what are replacement rules, how to modify their r.h.s, what about efficiency, what about rule ordering, etc). The method I suggested is also based on (global) replacement rules, and is (I think) a good compromise between avoiding mutable code and keeping things simple (particularly for users coming from other languages).

Comment: This comment was not at all a critique of your post (I upvoted it), just a complementary message :)